# Big Detail table and reporting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am going to design a schema for a checklist application where different branch user need to enter 28 fixed type of checklists and all 28 responses are going to go in a Detail table. So for example if we have 40 branches and altogether 40 users entering 28 records in detail table so my guess is 40 users * 28 records of each day * 320 days (holidays off) must be around  358400 records of every year.

So my question is to get the summarize reports by branch based on YEAR, MONTH and DATE RANGE criteria what should be my strategy for reporting. Should I use views (Fact tables) to get summaries done or make history tables alongwith detail tables or is it possible to fetch the reports from DETAIL table directly but with proper indexes? will it slow down?

Please suggest as I never dealt with large records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*400K is realy not a lot, not for a years worth of data.*

Stick to the single table, and correct indexes approach.

**Dont optimize before the whistle blows.**